# How to apply SQL query in Django?

Tags: django

**Following is a SQL query**

`update myModel set name="new name", age=24 where id==2`

**How can I apply above type of query in Django??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), this may help:

```
myModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(name='new name', age=24)
```

Comment: There was very less time to make this project.....It was my last semester project of Engineering.....With your help its done....I am Highly thankfull to you